Computing the Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left[ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} - \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \right]$
Problem Statement:
Let $\displaystyle a_{n} = \frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^{2}4^{n}}$.
$$
\mbox{Compute the limit:}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{n\left[\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_{n}} - \left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)^{1/3} \right]\right\}
$$
Hence, show that $a_{n} \to 0$.
Context:

No using L'Hospital's Rule and the concept of functions or continuity as that would be circular reasoning.
Just the concept(s) of formal definition of limits, arithmetic laws of limits, squeeze theorem, and general comparison of limits, sequence ratio/root tests.

Sequence Ratio test:
Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = L
\end{align*}
Where $0\leq L < 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n =0$
Simplified form of the expression:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left[ \frac{n+1/2}{n+1} - \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]
\end{align*}
Have tried to to use the sequence ratio test by
\begin{align*}
b_n := n\left[ \frac{n+1/2}{n+1} - \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]
\end{align*}
But, this gave inconclusive results of $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{0}{0}$.
Manipulation of the limit expression using the arithmetic laws of limits is blocked by the $n$ term as $\lim_{n\to \infty} n$ does not exist.
How does one go about computing the limit of sequences of this variety?

I meant that it diverges/ does not coverge to any finite $L \in \mathbb{R}$. To use the arithmetic laws of limits, the limits must exist.

Just  write $h=1/n$ and write $$(1+\frac{h}{2})(1+h)=1+\frac{3h}{2}+h\epsilon_1(h),\ (1+h)^2=1+2h+ h\epsilon_2(h),\ \frac{1}{(1+h)^{1/3}}=1-\frac{h}{3}+h\epsilon_3(h)$$ where $\epsilon_i(h)\to _{h\to 0}0$ for $i=1,2,3.$ you will get the desired limit.

@LetacGérard, your answer uses taylor series, which is beyond the scope here.

Can you use equivalents ?

@ClaudeLeibovici, could you elaborate?

I like this limit question

Note that:
$$n\left[\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}-\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]
=\frac{n}{n+1}\left[(n+1/2)-\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)^2}\right].$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}-\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[(n+1/2)-\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)^2}\right]\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1/2)^3-n(n+1)^2}{(n+1/2)^2+(n+1/2)\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)^2}+[n(n+1)^2]^{\frac23}}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac12n^2-\frac14n+\frac18}{(n+1/2)^2+(n+1/2)\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)^2}+[n(n+1)^2]^{\frac23}}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac12-\frac1{4n}+\frac1{8n^2}}{(1+1/(2n))^2+(1+1/(2n))\sqrt[3]{(1+1/n)^2}+[(1+1/n)^2]^{\frac23}}\\
=-\frac16.$$
Added：
$$\left[(n+1/2)-\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)^2}\right]
=n\left[1+1/(2n)-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\frac23}\right]\\
=n\left[1+1/(2n)-\left(1+\frac23\cdot\frac1n+o(1/n)\right)\right]\\
=-\frac16+o(1)\to-\frac16\quad n\to\infty.$$

Using  $A^3-B^3 = (A-B)(A^2 +AB + B^2)$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{n+1/2}{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{n+1}} 
&= \frac{\frac{(n+1/2)^3}{(n+1)^3}-  \frac{n}{n+1}} {\left(\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}\right)^2 +\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{n+1}}  + \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^2   } \\
&= \frac{-\frac{4 n^2 + 2 n - 1}{8 (n + 1)^3}}{\left(\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}\right)^2 +\frac{n+1/2}{n+1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{n+1}}  + \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^2}
\end{split}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Let me call your while expression $A_n$. Notice, that there is the identity $\Gamma(1/2 + n) = \sqrt{\pi} \frac{(2n)!}{n! 4^n}$. Then you have $$a_n = \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi} n!}$$ and yields your simplification. Taking both limits infovidually you habe a $0\cdot\infty$ situation. Recall, that one can express $1/\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}/n$, so we will do the same. We get $$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{1/3} = \frac{n^{1/3} (1+n)^{2/3}}{n+1}$$
This amounts to
$$ A_n = \frac{n}{n+1} \left(n - (n (n+1)^2)^{1/3} + 1/2\right)$$
It is always good to check the individual limits. So, set $B_n = n - (n(n+1)^2)^{1/3}$. Recall that one can compute limits of $\sqrt{b_n} - \sqrt{c_n}$ by multiplying by $1$, using the identity $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$. Let us do the same, just for the third power, where $$ x^3 - y^3 = (x-y) (x^2 + x y + y^2)$$
So, $x=n$ and $y=(n (n+1)^2)^{1/3}$. Then
\begin{align*}
x^2 + x y + y^2 &= n^2 + (n (n + 1)^2)^{1/3} n + (n (n + 1)^2)^{2/3} \\ &= n^2 (1 + (1 + 1/n)^{2/3} + (1 + 1/n)^{4/3})\\
x^3 - y^3 &= -n^2 (2 + 1/n)\\
B_n &= \frac{-(2 + 1/n)}{1 + (1 + 1/n)^{2/3} + (1 + 1/n)^{4/3}} \to -\frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
by continuity of the roots as $n\to\infty$. So the limit of $B_n$ and $n/(n+1)$ both individually exists. That gives then
\begin{equation*}
A_n \to 1\cdot \left( -\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{equation*}

Latex  takes too long on mobile devices… Any advice?

The expression can be represented as $${n\over 2(n+1)}-\left ({n\over n+1}\right )^{4/3}\,[-(n+1)]\left [\left (1-{1\over n+1}\right )^{2/3}-1\right ]$$ The limit of the last two factors is equal by definition to $f'(1),$ where $f(x)=x^{2/3},$ i.e. to ${2\over 3}.$ Thus the result is equal ${1\over 2}-{2\over 3}=-{1\over 6}.$

Let $\;x_n=\dfrac n{n+1}\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,.\quad(\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=1\;)$
It results that, $\quad n(x_n-1)=-x_n\;\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,.$
Moreover,
$\begin{align}b_n&=n\left[\dfrac{n+1/2}{n+1}-\left(\dfrac n{n+1}\right)^{\!\frac13}\right]=n\big(x_n-\sqrt[3]{x_n}\big)+\dfrac12x_n=\\[3pt]&=n\sqrt[3]{x_n}\big(\sqrt[3]{x_n}+1\big)\big(\sqrt[3]{x_n}-1\big)+\dfrac12x_n=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{n(x_n-1)\sqrt[3]{x_n}\big(\sqrt[3]{x_n}+1\big)}{\sqrt[3]{x_n^2}+\sqrt[3]{x_n}+1}+\dfrac12x_n=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac12x_n-\dfrac{x_n\sqrt[3]{x_n}\big(\sqrt[3]{x_n}+1\big)}{\sqrt[3]{x_n^2}+\sqrt[3]{x_n}+1}\qquad\text{for any }n\in\Bbb N\,.\end{align}$
Hence,
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\dfrac12-\dfrac23=-\dfrac16\,.$

Now we will prove that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\,.$
Since $\;\;n!\sim\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot n^n}{e^n}\;\;$ as $\;n\to\infty\;,\;$ it follows that
$a_n=\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2\!\cdot\!4^n}\sim\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;\;$ as $\;n\to\infty\;,\;$ hence,
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}=0\,.$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$
$$L:= \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)= \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} -1 + 1 \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}-1\right)+ \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(1-\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)$$
$$= \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}  \left(\frac{-n}{2n+2}\right)+ \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)$$
It is easy to see that $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}  \left(\frac{-n}{2n+2}\right)= \frac{-1}{2}$
For $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)$ let $h =1/n$, $$\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)= \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \frac{ \left(1-\left(1-h\right)^{\frac 1 3}\right)}{h}= -\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)^{frac{1}{x}} \bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{1}{3}$$
So $L=\frac {-1}6$
